# Как вывести число до N знаков после запятой?

Tags: java, вывод

Нужно выводить число на N знаков после запятой, даже если там идут нули.
N вводится юзером, кто-нибудь знает как сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать это можно с помощью функции [System.out.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). Она позволяет делать форматированный вывод. Например:

```
System.out.printf("%.6f\n", 3.14);
```

Выведет:

```
3.140000
```

Соответственно, в вашем случае можно написать так:

```
System.out.printf("%." + Integer.toString(N) + "f\n", a);
```

https://ideone.com/6QCWps

Если вы хотите получить саму форматированную строку, чтобы потом её как-то использовать, можно применить метод [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). Пример:

```
String format = String.format("%.6f\n", 3.14);
```

https://ideone.com/K8nF1K